# Knockoutjs After Render renders an Html comment

Tags: knockout.js

I noticed a strange behavior in Knockout's template rendering.

I have a simple Knockout example...

```
var viewModel = {
    stuff : ko.observable([{ id : 1, name : 'Thing'},
        { id: 2, name : 'Thingier' },
        { id : 3, name : 'Thingiest' }]),
    render: function(el){
        console.log(el);
    }
}

$(function(){
    ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
});
```

And the Html...

```
<ul data-bind="template: { name: 'thingTemplate',
                           foreach: stuff,
                           afterRender: render }">

</ul>
<!--
<script id="thingTemplate" type="text/html">
    <li>
        <span data-bind="text: name"></span>
    </li>
</script>-->

<script id="thingTemplate" type="text/html">
        <span data-bind="text: name"></span>
</script>
```

When the render function is called when using the template which is currently commented out, I get a console.log of **jQuery(li)**.

When the reunder function is called with the current template I get console.log of **jQuery(Comment { length=0, nodeName="#comment", nodeType=8, more...}, span)**.

What's with that comment node?

Here's the working fiddle... http://jsfiddle.net/jcreamer898/fqrv7/

Comment: It's not that it doesn't work, it's that the el passed to the render function has an html comment AND the span tag that was rendered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [KnockoutJS documentation](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/template-binding.html), the afterRender callback will be invoked, passing "an array of DOM nodes just rendered by the template." In other words, your render callback should be expecting an array of nodes.

Now, your question is why are you seeing a comment element coming back. My question is, do you see that same comment element even if you remove your <li> block?

Comment: With the li, I do not see the comment, without it, I do see the comment... It's strange...

Comment: Hmm. I'm not seeing that with KO 1.3 beta. Have you tried that version? Perhaps we are seeing a 1.2 bug.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, see:
[KnockoutJS template 'beforeRemove' called three times instead of 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7662781/knockoutjs-template-beforeremove-called-three-times-instead-of-1)

My solution was the following (not great, I know..):

```
afterAdd: function(elem) {
     if (elem.nodeName == '#comment') { return; } // <-- This line

     try {
        jQuery(elem).hide().fadeIn(2000);
     } catch (e) {
       console.log(e);
     } 
}
```

Comment: `if (elem.nodeType === 1) { jQuery(elem).hide().fadeIn(2000); }` cleaner solution